# Facebook social Comments Plugin Page-based Moderation - "Moderation Tool" link missing

Tags: facebook

I'm trying to set up the Facebook social Comments Plugin and use the Page-based Moderation View. I've added all the necessary code, but the "Moderation Tool" link does not appear next to the Comments box. The page does not require a logon. What am I doing wrong? The page is http://www.ergo-sum.net/music/MaudIrving.html and you can see the source to see the code I put in it.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

Answer (score 0):

You will need to set up the [OG tags](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters#markup) correctly for your page. Also the value of `<meta property="fb:admins" content="..."/>` should be your user id and not URL to your profile. Once you fix these issues, run you URL through the [URL debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/) to ensure that the crawler has picked up the new values correctly. It will also display any issues that you URL may have and you will need to fix those as well.